# Using classes for JSON serialization

Tags: vb.net, json.net

All, 
I need some help with understanding how classes can work with vb.NET and JSON.NET. I'm completely new to this. I've tried searching for answers, but I'm probably not asking the right questions. Here's my dilemma:

I have a JSON that I need to send to a REST API.

```
{
"paInfo":[
{
    "providerAccountName":"someClient",
    "providerAccountDescription":"A fine client.",
    "providerName":"provider",
    "externalProviderIdentifier":"BU4377890111"
},
{
    "providerAccountName":"someClient1",
    "providerAccountDescription":"A fine client.",
    "providerName":"provider",
    "externalProviderIdentifier":"BU4377890111"
}
],
    "hubAccountName":"test"
}
```

I ran this through https://jsonutils.com/ to build my class as:

```
Public Class PaInfo
    Public Property providerAccountName As String
    Public Property providerAccountDescription As String
    Public Property providerName As String
    Public Property externalProviderIdentifier As String
End Class

Public Class addHubAcct
    Public Property paInfo As PaInfo()
    Public Property hubAccountName As String
End Class
```

From there, I'm trying to assign values to the class properties, but I don't quite understand how to pass the values for PaInfo to the property.  Below is a snippet of code I'm using to assign values.  If I try to assign `a.paInfo = p`, it errors:

> error BC30311: Value of type 'PaInfo' cannot be converted to
>   'PaInfo()'

If I don't pass anything through to `a.paInfo`, I get a zero-length string in the JSON serialization.

```
Private Sub serializeAcct()
    Dim p As New PaInfo
    Dim a As New addHubAcct

    p.providerAccountName = "Test\name'This ""that and the other'"
    p.providerAccountDescription = "acct desc"
    p.providerName = "tester"
    p.externalProviderIdentifier = "123456"

    a.hubAccountName = "Tester"
    a.paInfo = p  'Here's my hangup

    Dim o As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a)
    Dim deserializedProduct As addHubAcct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of addHubAcct)(o)
    Stop

End Sub

?o.tostring,nq
{"paInfo":null,"hubAccountName":"Tester"}
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  `it errors` is not a useful problem description

Comment: Your message is not a JSON issue.  addHubAcct.painfo is an array, but the p object is a single instance, not an array

Comment: `paInfo` could be a List rather than an array, but in either case you need to create the instance before you can use it

Answer (score 0):

Change the `addHubAcct` class like this:

```
Public Class addHubAcct
    Public Property paInfo As New List(Of PaInfo)()
    Public Property hubAccountName As String
End Class
```

And then change the bad line in `serializeAcct()` like this:

```
a.paInfo.Add(p)
```

You likely have other problems as well, but that should get you past the current obstacle.

Answer (score 0):

Using List and .ToArray is what I was missing with my original code.

```
Private Sub serializeAcct()
    Dim p1 As New PaInfo
    Dim ps As New List(Of PaInfo)

    Dim a As New addHubAcct

    p1.providerAccountName = "Test\name'This ""that and the other'"
    p1.providerAccountDescription = "acct desc"
    p1.providerName = "tester"
    p1.externalProviderIdentifier = "123456"

    ps.Add(p1)

    a.hubAccountName = "Tester"
    a.paInfo = ps.ToArray


    Dim o As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a)


End Sub
```